# Can we create a generic Kibana dashboard template in ndjson format which can then be imported to create new dashboard based on a new data view?

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack

I am working on a use case where I need to create a new Kibana dashboard based on a new data view that can be dynamically created from an index pattern in ES.
I read from here -
[can you create visuals programmatically in Kibana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69061320/can-you-create-visuals-programmatically-in-kibana)
that one can create a template in ndjson format and swap out the variable parts to create a new dashboard. I tried to swap out the variable parts however it ended up replacing the old dashboard that I had exported to get the ndjson template earlier.

If anyone has a working solution or ideas about creating a working generic Kibana dashboard template that can be imported programmatically to create a new dashboard based on new data views then it will be of great help to folks like me here. Thanks in advance.